# Can I setup my own SMS WEBSITE. How?

Tags: php, web, sms, sms-gateway

I'm new to this site, and also i am not a super coder, so please have some patience with me, another thing is that i have a really small bandwidth, so please if you could send me an email it would be wonderful.

So all I want to know is how to add some sms support in my website so i can send messages to my users. I understand that carriers provide some paid service. What i,m looking for is a cheap service to send sms to several country including Cuba. Please any approach would be nice.

Comment: many many sms providers you can use to integrate sending\receiving sms

Comment: Abraham - welcome to Stackoverflow. please review the FAQ and about.

Answer (score 1):

Most carries have a dedicated email domain set up to send SMS messages to the devices on their network. AT&T's, for example, is "*number*@txt.att.net", you can look up the rest on google. This service is free to you, but the recipient still gets charged for the message so don't go spamming people willy nilly. Also, the recipient can NOT reply to your message, that is a service that you need to pay for.

Comment: most in the western world, perhaps, but not most globally.

Comment: Any amount of volume via this technique and you'll get shut off quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send SMS messages internationally, I'd suggest going with [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/) because Twilio's international coverage is still only in private beta.

If you'll only be sending domestically (i.e. within the United States or Canada), [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) has a clear and straight-forward API as well as reasonable tariff prices.

Comment: Voice calls or SMS messages within the United States

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of SMS gateway providers available that provide a simple Web Service API that can be integrated into websites. Many also provide international support for a variety of countries.

A quick Google search for "SMS web service" will get you a good selection of vendors to choose from.

Do make sure to pick a reputable vendor. At my last company, we had an issue when the US operators shut off Clickatel's shared shortcode. A bunch of companies, including us, were on the same shortcode... unfortunately some of them were doing shady/spammy things and when the carriers took action all customers paid the price.